# Getting ClassNotFoundException while using eclipseLink with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, persistence, eclipselink, java-11

I m using eclipseLink with gradle in my Java project

this is my gradle dependency configuration

```
dependencies {
    compile(group:"org.eclipse.persistence", name:"eclipselink", version:"2.7.4.K3", changing: true) 
    
    ...
}
```

when I run my application I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.ValueHolderInterface
```

did I miss something in my gradle configuration ?

Comment: Does it compile? Seems odd, maybe look at how you are running your app. The ValueHolderInterface is what EclipseLink puts into your entity classes to allow for lazy fetching, so maybe check if you are serializing entities to somewhere that doesn't have the EclipseLink dependency - it needs to be tied to your model classes.

Comment: Could you, please, share the whole build.gradle file

Comment: @Chris, yes it compiles

Comment: Did you check serialization? You didn't put any context on where you are getting this exception from - the stack, and how that part of the application was started/loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version: '2.7.4'
```

and it should be fine.

Comment: unfortunately that does not solve my problem

Comment: ValueHolderInterface class is there. There is something else wrong with the project. Can you try to compile it directly via Gradle? What do you see?